# Yii unable to resolve request for some urls but not all

Tags: php, url, yii

I am trying to set up a page in Yii framework but the URL routing is breaking some pages but some still work.

I noticed the pages which have a hyphen (-) work and the ones which dont break.

For example

```
/mypage/my-item (works) 
/mypage/myitem (breaks)
```

I use the same code on other pages and I do not have this issue so it is very weird.

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
                        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                        // SECTORS DOES NOT WORK
                        'sectors'=>'site/sectors',  
                        'sectors/<sector:.*?>'=>'site/sectors',                         
                        // PERSPECTIVE WORKS FINE
                        'perspective'=>'site/perspective',  
                        'perspective/<article:.*?>'=>'site/perspective',    
        ),
    ),
```

If I try putting die() into the controller it still throws the error so for some reason the /mypage/myitem URL does not even make it to the correct controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was the order of the URL rules. I moved the first three  rules to the bottom of the array and it fixed it. I assume the first ones were coming true before the sectors/ rules.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to change the hyphen to underscores. Or better yet, change all urls to an single word; no more special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression **\w+** doesn't include **-** symbol. So your example urls will be parsed by different rules.